# Trained network predicts NaN output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on an autoencoder to encode/decode german titles of articles (~2k samples). I am using byte pair encoding as a compromise between character encoding and word encoding. This is the model i am using for this:

```py
def create_model(characters, enc_size, latent_dim): #my parameter values: 32, 512, 32
    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(characters, enc_size))
    encoded = tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(128, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
    encoded = tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(latent_dim)(encoded)

    vector = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
    decoded = tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(characters)(vector)
    decoded = tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(128, return_sequences=True)(decoded)
    decoded = tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(enc_size, return_sequences=True)(decoded)

    encoder = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs, encoded)
    decoder = tf.keras.models.Model(vector, decoded)

    auto = encoder(inputs)
    auto = decoder(auto)
    auto = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs, auto)

    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3)
    auto.compile(optimizer=opt,
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=["accuracy"])
    auto.summary()

    return auto, encoder, decoder
```

I created its structure, by modifying the Sequence-to-Sequence example in this keras [article](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html). Training this model is no problem. The loss decreases, while the accuracy increases. During this whole process both never become NaN. Now, when i try to use it in prediction (model.predict) the output is an array filled with NaNs. The strange thing is, that if i use "binary_crossentropy" (although it is not really suited for this task, because byte pairs are one hot encoded) instead of "categorical_crossentropy" this does not happen and the prediction after training is not NaN. But it seems, that the actual output does not really improve, even after 200 epochs. I cant really tell by the "binary_accuracy" because of the fact, that it is unsuited.

One of the best predicted examples:

> Original: "luegde einbruch in wohnhaus" | Prediction: "moren einbruch in einbruch in diebstagesuchteinbruchbrandeses"

I am also certain, that the dataset is not contaminated with NaNs or Infs.
Does anyone knwo a solution/reason for this strange behaviour, or knows a working example of an autoencoder for text with encoder and decoder model.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try changing your optimizer, also let the optimizer choose its learning rate.

Comment: How do you call the model for prediction?

Comment: I have already tried SGD with the same nan problem. How do i let the optimizer choose (leave call empty?)

Comment: I simply use data from the generator i use for training: for g in generator: pred = model.predict(g[0])